# How can I have just one google calendar?

Tags: gmail, calendar, google-workspace, google-calendar

As a 1099 consultant I have a few clients and they all have their own google calendar system for their domain. I get a new andrew@foo.com email for each one and I end up having to keep multiple google calendar tabs open. I've tried adding the andrew@foo.com calendar to my personal calendar under "Other Calendars" -> "Subscribe To Calendar" and I get:

[image]

But the default seems to be "See only/free busy (hide details)" so I end up with:

[image]

Seeing only free/busy for my various 1099 client calendars on my main personal gmail calendar. Is there a way to have everything work nicely from my own personal gmail calendar which I own and is a permanent part of my life vs. these other calendars that come and go as the client work starts and ends?

Answer (score 0):

I put all my customer appointments in my own Calendar with my own notes.

Over the long haul, this works vastly better than to trying to adapt other calendars into mine.  Some customers use Google, some use Outlook, some use Thunderbird, and others use something else.

I have used my own calendar for many years.

Comment: but what about invites from the CEO at company foo sent to my @foo.com calendar? How do I easily just automatically forward that vs having to re-enter the info?

Comment: When you accept an invite, it goes into your own calendar, not a new one.

Comment: i'm not seeing this. It always going into the @foo.com calendar. Can you tell me how step by step?

Comment: I do not see how you can merge differing calendars into one page.

Answer (score 0):

Your client controls @foo.com

Dear client,

Please grant "See all event details" to andrew@foo.com for calendar "calendar name here".  You may need assistant from your IT team.

Thanks
andrew

Comment: you gotta be kiddin me. I have six of these clients and no way will I get 100% compliance.

Comment: @AndrewArrow  It is the simplest solution, from the perspective of not having to duplicate them in some other way.  You only have 6 clients this way?  That is only 6 emails, I would send the emails and see if you get compliance vs assuming they won't comply.  It will take someone (a 1 time change) at the company 30 seconds of effort vs any other solution will take more than 30 seconds.

Comment: no, but then there will be 6 more NEW clients and the solution is not to do this every time. The solution is to work around this default google has in some creative way.

Comment: You can have them export the calendar to an ical file and then import the calendar, but then you will have to have them do this for every calendar change.  This will be 10x more time consuming than my original solution.  Manually duplicating events on your calendar for every appointment will take even more time.  They can share the calendar another way, but you won't get any more data because your account doesn't have enough permissions.